# Make Javascript File Publically Available

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to make a javascript file accessible from my web server.

So that anyone can access and reference it in their websites.

e-g Suppose abcxyzserver.com is my webserver.

www.abcxyzserver.com/Public/test.js

how can i make it possible that putting above link in the src of script tags will reference this js file.

Comment: Cannot understand where's the problem. If public directory it's not protected by a whatever authorization system, test.js will be publicly readable by anyone and usable as <script type="text/javascript" src="www.abcxyzserver.com/Public/test.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, just make the file accessible in the normal way, just like an HTML or CSS file. `script` tags aren't subject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which is why Google, Microsoft, and others can offer script downloads from their CDNs (just for completeness: [Google's is here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/), [Microsoft's is here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn)).